# Get List of Youtube channels subscribe by current user in android?

Tags: unity-game-engine, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Hello I want to get list of channels subscribe by current user in android.

Steps I follow:

1) https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

By read the description, I created **API key** for android and **oauth** key in google developer console and tired to implement following request

[GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mine=true&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D). you can see I have set only `part = snippet` and `mine = true`.

For authentication I followed https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html

Here is my code

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Bundle options = new Bundle();

am.getAuthToken(
    myAccount_,                     // Account retrieved using getAccountsByType()
    "Manage your tasks",            // Auth scope
    options,                        // Authenticator-specific options
    this,                           // Your activity
    new OnTokenAcquired(),          // Callback called when a token is successfully acquired
    new Handler(new OnError()));    // Callback called if an error occurs
```

After adding proper permission I can get my account in myAccount_

on call backbaack of **TokenAcquire**

```
private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
        // Get the result of the operation from the AccountManagerFuture.
        Bundle bundle = result.getResult();

        // The token is a named value in the bundle. The name of the value
        // is stored in the constant AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN.
        token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
        ...
    }
}
```

**I am not getting the token value**.

Please guide me. **Is there some alternative approach** Or if have to update/modify something?

My permission in xml are

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

I am getting error at this line `token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);` in my catch of exception handling.

> android.accounts.AuthenticatorException.
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I am using android 6.0 and it require run time permission.

Comment: Paste your full error code

Comment: android.accounts.AuthenticatorException

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference....

Comment: token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN); here i got error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To successfully get the access token according to [Obtain an access token](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Client_Side_Web_Applications_Flow), I think you need to use a valid scope which is `'https://gdata.youtube.com'` for Youtube API. However, looking at your code, it seems you passed "Manage your tasks" as Auth scope. Try setting that to `'https://gdata.youtube.com'` instead.

With regard to getting number of subscribers, try making a [REST call in Android](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) with the following URI GET request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mySubscribers=true&fields=pageInfo&key={SERVER_API_KEY}
```

It returns a JSON response where totalResults represents the number of subscribers:

```
{
   "pageInfo": {
   "totalResults": 2,
   "resultsPerPage": 5
  }
}
```

Comment: Change my scope to ''https://gdata.youtube.com'' but still getting android.accounts.AuthenticatorException

Comment: what is server_api_key? and part=snippet?